# How to stop a program with infinity loop in Python (tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I have a problem with stopping the program. When I click exit button, the mainloop stops but program is still running. I am new to it and I have no idea what to do. I know the issue is the thread is still running and I don't know how to stop it.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import simulation as s
import graph as g
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog
import threading


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Simulator")
    switch = True

    def get_filename():
        return filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root)

    def play():
        def run():
            while switch:
                s.simulation(s.particle, np.inf, s.initial_time_step, get_filename())

        thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
        thread.start()

    def start_simulation():
        global switch
        switch = True
        v.set('Simulation is running!')
        play()

    def stop_simulation():
        global switch
        v.set('Simulation is stopped!')
        switch = False

    def draw_graphs():
        g.create_graphs()

    start = Button(root, text='Start simulation', command=start_simulation, width=50)
    start.pack()
    finish = Button(root, text='Stop simulation', command=stop_simulation, width=50)
    finish.pack()
    graphs = Button(root, text='Graphs', command=draw_graphs, width=50)
    graphs.pack()
    exit_button = Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy, width=50)
    exit_button.pack()
    v = StringVar()
    statement = Label(root, textvariable=v)
    statement.pack()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can call `stop_simulation()` before destroying the main window.  Or set the thread to daemon mode.

Comment: Daemon mode works, thanks!

Comment: You should change all `global switch` to `nonlocal switch` because `switch` is local variable in `main()`, not global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for the exit button which also stops your thread

```
def exit():
    switch = False
    root.destroy()
```

And later:

```
exit_button = Button(root, text='Exit', command=exit, width=50)
```

You can also call the same method whenever the window is closed with the top right X button. Just bind your method to the event:

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)
```

Ps: You dont need to use global here, because your nested functions have access to the outer functions variables

Comment: It works in the same way. Mainloop is stopped but the script is still running. I need click stop button in PyCharm to stop the script.

Comment: @ArturOwczarek I think what you are seeing is PyCharm is stopping the interpreter not the script. Have you tried `quit()`?